# docker-compose images volumes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, digital-ocean, docker-compose

I am using docker-machine, Mac OS X, drivers digitalocean and default virtualbox.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.2.0
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev
RUN mkdir /myapp-web-api
WORKDIR /myapp-web-api
ADD Gemfile /myapp-web-api/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp-web-api/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp-web-api
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
web:
  build: .
  command: rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp-web-api
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

When I am using local virtualbox driver volumes mapping is fine. But when I switch env to digitalocean begins some issue with images.

docker-compose build is OK

```
Boriss-MacBook-myapp-web-api wwtlf$ docker-compose ps
Name                    Command               State    Ports 
------------------------------------------------------------------
myappwebapi_db_1    /docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Exit 0         
myappwebapi_web_1   rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0       Exit 1         
Boriss-MacBook-myapp-web-api wwtlf$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
myappwebapi_web      latest              4c95e37708ff        22 minutes ago      927 MB
postgres            latest              b305a133422a        13 days ago         265.1 MB
ruby                2.2.0               ac90cee00759        10 months ago       774.7 MB
Boriss-MacBook-Pro:myapp-web-api wwtlf$
```

When I try to start containers:

```
Boriss-MacBook-Pro:myapp-web-api wwtlf$ docker-compose up
Starting myappwebapi_db_1
Starting myappwebapi_web_1
Attaching to myappwebapi_db_1, myappwebapi_web_1
db_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-12-19 07:34:21 UTC
db_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
web_1 | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/definition.rb:22:in `build': /myapp-web-api/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
web_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler.rb:155:in `definition'
web_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `setup'
web_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
web_1 |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
web_1 |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
web_1 |     from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
web_1 |     from /usr/local/bundle/bin/rails:14:in `<main>'
myappwebapi_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Hmm, let's check the volumes:

```
docker-compose run web /bin/bash
Starting myappwebapi_db_1
root@155e09fc57ac:/myapp-web-api# ls
root@155e09fc57ac:/myapp-web-api#
```

Empty:(
Let's try another way:

```
Boriss-MacBook-Pro:myapp-web-api wwtlf$ docker run -i -t myappwebapi_web /bin/bash
root@ee53fea29f97:/myapp-web-api# ls
Dockerfile  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  README.rdoc  Rakefile  app  bin  config  config.ru  db  docker-compose.yml  lib  log  public  test  tmp  vendor
root@ee53fea29f97:/myapp-web-api#
```

what's the difference between the docker-compose run and the docker run???

Looks line I connect to different image...

UPD:

I found that
**docker-compose run web /bin/bash**
Folder **/myapp-web-api** has mapped to root@myapp-prod:**/Users/wwtlf/Projects/MYAPP/myapp-web-api** folder on digitalocean VM, but not to host.

Answer (score 1):

> what's the difference between the `docker-compose run` and the `docker run`???

The difference is the volumes part of the docker-compose.yml file:

```
volumes:
    - .:/myapp-web-api
```

> This command mounts the host directory, ., into the container at /myapp-web-api.
>   **If the path `/myapp-web-api` already exists inside the container’s image, the `./` mount overlays but does not remove the pre-existing content**.

The `docker-compose up` command overwrites temporarily the content of  `/myapp-web-api` as specifed in the Dockerfile `ADD` directives.

This isn't the case with the `docker run -i -t myappwebapi_web /bin/bash`  command, which does not mount any host folder.

Comment: /myapp-web-api exists inside the containers image.
Why docker-compose up does not overwrite?
Why docker run and docker-compose run looks like I connect to different images?

Comment: @WWTLF docker-compose up does overwrite `/myapp-web-api` with the host content of '.'. While docker run does not everwrite anything, and keep `/myapp-web-api` content defined by the Dockerfile.

Comment: @WWTLF if '.' (current folder) is empty on the digital ocean VM, you would see an empty folder. While, again, the docker run command does not mount anything, so you still see the content you defined in the Dockerfile.

Comment: The issue is host '.' is not empty! Why docker-compose up does not take the content of host's current folder and overwrite /myapp-web-api on the image? I suppose it takes it from VM folder, but not from host... When I was using VirtualBox VM, there was shared folder to /Users, but when I use digitalocean driver, there is no sharing between host and VM.

Comment: @WWTLF can you try `./:/myapp-web-api` instead of `.:/myapp-web-api` (just in case it makes a difference)

Comment: I just removed volumes section from compose file, for PROD for my task it is OK, for DEV I will create a new compose file and will use the VitrualBox VM.
I also tried to use docker-osx-dev, but it is raw and has a lot of bugs.